# Realtime analytics stats API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

How do I fetch realtime stats from the analytics API? The documentation and examples does not work with the newest Google API:

Examples:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get#examples

Library installed:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

I have the analytics reporting for non-realtime statistics working, only trying to find how to get the realtime number of visitors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "The documentation and examples does not work with the newest Google API:" What error are you getting when you attempt to run the example? By the "newest Google API" do you mean the most recent "PHP client library?". Or do you the Analytics Reporting API V4?

Comment: I found out the library can handle both v3 and v4 documentation, so after some more digging around I got it working using the documentation. Thanks for the reply.